# I can't find the SIM card slot on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Tags: sim-card, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, but there is no SIM card slot available to put in. Is there any adapter or another way to put the SIM card and use it?

Comment: Is it made for mobile data or is it only the wifi version?

Comment: If you can't find it, then there's a very big chance that you have WiFi-only model, so no SIM card for HSDPA.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a Sim Card slot, it will be very clearly printed right on the back of the Tablet, as it is with my Galaxy Tab 2 T715.